# CMake : produce Makefiles in each subdirectory?

Tags: cmake

Assuming the following configuration :

```
parentdir1/parentdir2/myproject
parentdir1/parentdir2/myproject/CMakeLists.txt
parentdir1/parentdir2/myproject/src
parentdir1/parentdir2/myproject/src/dir1
parentdir1/parentdir2/myproject/src/dir2
parentdir1/parentdir2/myproject/src/dir3
```

Currently, my CMakeLists produces only one Makefile in `parentdir1/parentdir2/myproject`.

How to produce a Makefile in each subdirectory (to compile the associated directory) ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake allows you to have a CMakeLists.txt file in any subdirectory under the root directory of your source tree.

Then use the **add_subdirectory** command in CMakeLists.txt to add the subdirectories. Then CMake will look for CMakeLists.txt in those subdirectories.

See the documentation for the add_subdirectory command here:

http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_subdirectory

For more info, check out the CMake FAQ and documentation on www.cmake.org.